# Next js session

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a project on Next.js which is using some endpoints with token authorization. I am getting the token from Next's useSession, and my provider is Keycloak.
The issue is that when I stay on one page without navigating to another for more than one hour, which is the expiry duration of my token, I have a session with an expired access token. This situation causes my endpoints to return a 401 error. To get a new refreshed token, I have to switch to a different tab and then return to the tab I was on. Sometimes, when I do that, the token is undefined.My token rotation has been done on next auth.I guess I need a way to trigger it automatically from the client.